# c# "Cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a list in string to get the usernames like this:

```
string[] whitelisted = { "example", "exampøle222", "example245"};

if (sentRequest.Sender.Username.ToLower().Contains(whitelisted))
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: It says this as a error http://prntscr.com/b4i7jk

Comment: `whitelisted` is an array, but `Contains()` expects a single `string`. This is what the error message tells you. You probably want to check whether the user name is in the `whitelist`, not vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if the username contains the list. You should be checking that the list contains the username.

```
whitelisted.Contains(sentRequest.Sender.Username.ToLower())
```

Comment: Isn't that contains to be lower cased?

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is backwards. You need to see whether the array contains the string .

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check that the `sentRequest.Sender.Username.ToLower()` is present in the `whitelisted` list, right?

Then make it inverted `if (whitelisted.Contains(sentRequest.Sender.Username.ToLower()))`

The error you get says that the method you are calling i.e. `string.Contains()` can accept a `string` but cannot accept an array `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done quite simply using the LINQ aggregate function.

```
string[] strings = {"example1","example2"};
string result = strings.Aggrigate((l,r)=>l+r);
```

You could also use the String.Join method

```
string[] strings = {"example1","example2"};
string result = String.Join("",strings);
```

However when I look at the rest of your code I would recommend solving the problem something like this.

```
if(whitelisted.IndexOf(sentRequest.Sender.Username.ToLower()) != -1)
```

That if statement will only be executed if the Username is in the white list.